# When did the Polovtsy convert to Islam?

Tags: middle-ages, russia, islam, steppe-nomads

[Polovtsy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumans) is a name used to refer various Turkic tribes living to the East of Kievan Rus. I wonder, at what point did those Turkic peoples become Muslim?

Comment: I have read about the Cuman/Kypchak but only superficially. I understand they were part of the Tartar nationality is this true? If you are Cuman and Cumans are Muslims the spelling would have been Matin or Abdul matin (the servant of god) am I right? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumans) states:

> The Cumans, with the Turko-Mongols, adopted Islam, in the second half of the 13th and the first half of the 14th century.[30]
>   **Wikipedia asserts that Cumans is one of a number of synonyms for Polovtsy

The [cited article](http://encyclopediaofukraine.com/display.asp?linkPath=pages%5CC%5CU%5CCumans.htm) repeats the claim

> In the second half of the 13th and the first half of the 14th century the Cumans, together with the Tatars, adopted Islam.

Answer (score 1):

Cumans Kypchak people converted their religion to islam in the end of 17.century  with press

Comment: I know very well cause I am Cuman☺

Comment: what does "with press" mean?